# iOS: Take photo or select from library

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to get an image from the user as shown here.

[image]

This looks like a lot of work:

- see if device has camera
- create action sheet with appropriate options
- translate "Take Photo" and "Choose from Library" into every language my app supports
- look for response
- bring up image picker with selected image picking method
- get response, extract image from a dictionary
- dismiss picker

So the question is: first, am I missing any steps? Second, I have seen this done hundreds of times before in other apps, is there really no faster way to do this? Most importantly, I am not looking forward to adding strings to my project if there is a standard naming and translation already in the SDK.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created a library to take a photo or select from library as a response to the question above and share for you at: https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake

This works great so far for photos. [UPDATE] Also does videos now.

Homepage at: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fdtake